# Creating OCaml binding from C++ with Swig

Tags: c++, binding, ocaml, swig

I am creating a C++ package with just about everything being wrapped in a class and am testing out using Swig to create different bindings for my project. Right now I am looking into the process for OCaml using the documentation [here](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ocaml.html) as the main point of reference. I am fairly new to OCaml and Swig but I was able to successfully create the binding for Python with no hiccups but when trying for OCaml I am running into issues with using camlp4(I believe this is the default for swig so I did not bother with camlp5). I am running into issues specifically when running the following:

```
$ ocamlmktop -custom swig.cmo -I `camlp4 -where` camlp4o.cma swigp4.cmo example_wrap.o example.cmo -o example
```

I get the error

```
Error: Module `Dynlink' is unavailable (required by `Camlp4')
```

Before trying to use the Camlp4 util in my Swig process I was running the following to successfully compile the OCaml module:

```
    swig -c++ -ocaml -co swigp4.ml
    swig -c++ -ocaml example.i
    for file in swig.mli swig.ml swigp4.ml ; do swig -ocaml -co $$file ; done
    swig -ocaml -co swig.mli ; swig -ocaml -co swig.ml
    ocamlc -c swig.mli ; ocamlc -c swig.ml
    cp example_wrap.cxx example_wrap.c
    ocamlc -c -ccopt -xc++ example_wrap.c
    ocamlc -c example.mli
    ocamlc -c example.ml
```

The issue with this was trying to figure out calling the objects of my class within the top level. Since I am a beginner in the land of OCaml and functional programming as a whole, I am of course curious how to go about calling class methods of my original C++ code in OCaml after complete the Swig binding process (without camlp4)

Does anyone have experience with the C++->OCaml binding process using Swig have some pointers on how to properly perform this?